# WP7 - ContextMenu listbox item click event

Tags: vb.net, class, windows-phone-7, contextmenu, databound

Say I have the following data template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Height="95" Width="446" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="false" RenderTransformOrigin="0.3,0.526">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding categoryimage}" Height="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding categoryname}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0,-46,0" FontSize="26.667"/>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="MyContextMenu">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete console" Click="contextMenuAction_Click"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I want to handle when the context menu item is clicked. How would I access the list item as a class object (if this makes sense?)

I've tried the following code, however it's giving me a NullReferenceException exception:

```
Private Sub contextMenuAction_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim c As classes.consoles = listBoxview.SelectedItem
    MessageBox.Show(c.categoryname)

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get the parent item using the Visual Tree Helper, as detailed in the following thread :-

[Context menu selected item wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860569/context-menu-selected-item-wp7)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it working by converting the code on the question you linked to vb.net :)